# Casting dynamic firebase keys to a dictionary swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to take a dictionary value in Firebase and cast it to a 'User' class in my app with the setValuesForKeysWithDictionary method, but it keeps failing. If anyone could help explain it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
class User : NSObject{

var currentJob : String?
var currentOrg : String?
var hasJobs : Bool?
var hasOrganisations : Bool?
var isCurrentOrgAdmin : Bool?
var organisations : [String : AnyObject]?
}

var user = User()
func bindDataForCurrentUser() -> User {

    firebase.child("Users").child(currentUserID).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            print("dictionary \(dictionary)")
        self.user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            print("user: \(self.user)")
        }
    }
    return self.user
}
```

it's not making it to the second print line, but here is the dictionary it's printing in the first line:

> ["hasOrganisations": 1, "isCurrentOrgAdmin": 1, "currentOrg": -KQFGX4oNcYPjXhlPZ9t, "hasJobs": 0, "organisations": {
>       "-KQFGX4oNcYPjXhlPZ9t" = 1;"-KQFGZl-M4gSPTEjEXNH" = 1;}, "currentJob": -KQKQRfRYF4m3UAMaycd]

Thanks in advance for any help!
edit: Sorry forgot to add console error:

> dictionary ["hasOrganisations": 1, "isCurrentOrgAdmin": 1, "currentOrg": -KQFGX4oNcYPjXhlPZ9t, "hasJobs": 0, "organisations": { "-KQFGX4oNcYPjXhlPZ9t" = 1; "-KQFGZl-M4gSPTEjEXNH" = 1;}, "currentJob": -KQKQRfRYF4m3UAMaycd]
>
> 2016-08-29 13:00:08.909 iComply[49608:5287826] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hasOrganisations.'

Comment: Kindly update setValuesForKeysWithDictionary method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
class User : NSObject{

      var currentJob : String?
      var currentOrg : String?
      var hasJobs : Bool?
      var hasOrganisations : Bool?
      var isCurrentOrgAdmin : Bool?
      var organisations : [String : AnyObject]?
         }

   var user = User()

   func bindDataForCurrentUser() -> User {

       let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)

       ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
          print(snapshot.value)
           self.user = []

                     if let userDict = snap.value as? [String, AnyObject] {
                         let specificUser = User()
                         specificUser.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(userDict)
                         self.user.append(specificUser)
                      }

       })
     } 
  return self.user
}
```

PS:- if you have multiple queries to insert in a class, use  `var user = [User]()`  and inside **observeSingleEventOfType** iterate through each of of those dataSnap. Reason why i used **observeSingleEventOfType** over **observeEventType** because it removes the observer from the thread once done with it.. you can change it back to ***observeEventType*** if you want to keep listening to this thread...:)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot that single event type listener is great! I was having crashes as well through the listener continuing to go when it shouldn't be.Thanks!

Comment: Hi sorry I need 15 reputation points to do that, hopefully someone else who sees this can or I can once I have some more rep thanks again :)